# Addition of parameter in plsql.conf in oracle 11g R2

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am facing issue with the parameters while passing to the procedure.
got the below error: mod_plsql:package_name.procedure_name too many parameters passed in got in 2422 parameters upper limit is 2000.

For the above error i have added the PlsqlMaxParameters in plsql.conf file in testing and production environment.

In testing environment, i am not getting any error but getting the error in production environment even after rebooting the server.

Please provide pointer on this.

Comment: you can write your parameters to YOUR_table (create it for paramaters ) then in procedure use that values from YOUR_table .

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar the parameters vary every time.. What could be the issue in production? Why it is working fine in Testing environent but not in Production...

Comment: Probably because you have different environment on Test and Production regions ? You sure that you change right config file on Production ? Maybe it uses custom path ?

Comment: @Leo I have cross checked both the configurations file on both Test environment and production environment.They look same with o difference.